# adding future intervals in new column pandas faster

Tags: python, pandas, recurrent-neural-network

What I am trying to achieve is a faster way to append future values to my current row. My data-frame is a few GB so it takes hours to process on my computer. I am currently using the code below which achieves this goal. However I cant find the appropriate way to process it with pandas. I realize that iterating through a Data-frame in pandas is inefficient. Any wizards out there that can help?

```
days = pd.Series(data.day.unique())

for d in days:
    data_temp = data.loc[data['day'] == d]
    for i in range(0, 1439): #1439 number of min in a day

        t1 = data_temp.loc[data_temp['minutes'] == i]
        t2 = data_temp.loc[data_temp['minutes'] == i+5]
        t3 = data_temp.loc[data_temp['minutes'] == i+10]

        #Check if ID values exist in all three time intervals 
        ans = set(t1.ID) & set(t2.ID) & set(t3.ID)      
        ans_List = list(ans) 

        if (len(ans) >= 10):  #isolate only occurenses bigger than 10
            for j in range(10): 
                data_t1 = data_t1.append(t1.loc[t1.ID == ans_List[j]])
                data_t2 = data_t2.append(t2.loc[t2.ID == ans_List[j]])
                data_t3 = data_t3.append(t3.loc[t3.ID == ans_List[j]])

data_t1 = data_t1.reset_index(drop=True)
data_t2 = data_t2.reset_index(drop=True)
data_t3 = data_t3.reset_index(drop=True)

data_t1['a_t5'] = data_t2['a']
data_t1['b_t5'] = data_t2['b']
data_t1['c_t5'] = data_t2['c']

data_t1['a_t10'] = data_t3['a']
data_t1['b_t10'] = data_t3['b']
data_t1['c_t10'] = data_t3['c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending can be a bit of a killer. There are some speed-ups for you to enjoy.

First impression is that these lines:

```
for j in range(10): 
    data_t1 = data_t1.append(t1.loc[t1.ID == ans_List[j]])
    data_t2 = data_t2.append(t2.loc[t2.ID == ans_List[j]])
    data_t3 = data_t3.append(t3.loc[t3.ID == ans_List[j]])
```

can be speed up a touch by changing to this:

```
import intertools # Put at top of doc


data_t1 = itertools.chain(data_t1,[t1.loc[t1.ID == ans_List[j]] for j in range(10)]) 
data_t2 = itertools.chain(data_t2,[t2.loc[t1.ID == ans_List[j]] for j in range(10)]) 
data_t3 = itertools.chain(data_t3,[t3.loc[t3.ID == ans_List[j]] for j in range(10)])
```

List comprehension allows you to avoid constantly appending, and intertools concatenates the results quickly and efficiently, which is especially important with large data sets.